# How to initialize Pickle Counter List a unique ID and store it in a file and retrive it?

Tags: python, file, counter, pickle

Initializing unique ID to the output of Pickle's Counter and store them in file and retrive them for use.

In MySQL you can initialize Primary key and use them as Forigen Key. Same I want to do here using file system.

a=['a','a','a','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','d','d','e']

b=Counter(a)

b Counter({'a': 10, 'c': 8, 'b': 7, 'd': 2, 'e': 1})

### I have more than 83,000 elements in `b`

c Counter({ 'b': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 1})

d Counter({ 'c': 4, 'b': 2, 'd': 1})

### I have 20,000 Counters like `c` and `d`

First of all I want to initialize unique ID to all elements of `b` and store it in a file,

then I want to initialize same IDs to `c` and `d` with reference to IDs given to `b` and store them also in file.

I only know how to store counter and how to retrive it. Now my counter have a list of elements with their frequency. What I want to do is initialize a unique ID to every element of my master list which is in this case `b` and I want to  store it in a file like :

## ID Term Frequency

1    a         10

2    c           8

3    b           7

4    d           2

Like wise.

And then I want to initialize this ID at `c` and `d` like:

For c

## term_id term Frequency

3           b        3

4           d        1

and so on

For d

## term_id term Frequency

2           c        4

3           b        2

4           d        1

Comment: Hi Ali -- can you add to the question what you have tried to do and failed in the process?  What do you mean by a unique id?

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert I edited the question. Please check, thier I wanted to make table but I couldn't. I hape you might understand what I am tring to ask.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert Please help.

Comment: this looks really good -- hoping that someone w/ more knowledge can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make dictionary that maps each *term* to its *id*
Then use dictionary to make desired lists:

```
from collections import Counter
a=['a','a','a','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','d','d','e']
b=['a','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','d','e']
aCounter=Counter(a)
bCounter=Counter(b)
v=sorted(aCounter.keys()|bCounter.keys())
idDict={item:i for i,item in enumerate(v) }


bresult=[(idDict[item[0]],item[0],item[1]) for item in bCounter.items()]
aresult=[(idDict[item[0]],item[0],item[1]) for item in aCounter.items() ]
print(bresult)
print(aresult)
```

Output  :

> [(0, 'a', 5), (1, 'b', 4), (3, 'd', 1), (4, 'e', 1)]
>    [(0, 'a', 10), (1, 'b', 7), (2, 'c', 8), (3, 'd', 2), (4, 'e', 1)]

Union is performed using | operator. use sorted to assign id=0 to 'a'

Comment: You are really close to solve this problem of mine, I am confused in few thing,
First one I no idea how this loop works 'for i,item ' and second how this sequance of ' item[0]:i ' is being.

I just want list of 'a' for ID creation, but with your method of dictionary when it is taking OR for both counter Items the ID outpout is wrong.

While considering only 'a' for dictionary. i.e.
idDict={item[0]:i for i,item in enumerate(aCounter.items()) }
Output is {'b': 0, 'e': 1, 'c': 2, 'a': 3, 'd': 4}

While taking both as above.
{'a': 6, 'e': 4, 'd': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 7}
@Mehrdad Dowlatabadi

Comment: How this ID sequence is being decided here in your loop? @Mehrdad Dowlatabadi

Comment: I now only want to know on which criteria this ID is being allocated to the elements, i.e. Which element will get '0' ID and which one will get '1' and so on.

And if its possible for you then please explain this also that how this OR functioning in enumerate().

Thats all.

Comment: Really thanks for your help.
I actually got from here what actually I want, but the above logic is not correct because it will lose some of the ID's while doing the union operation. Execute the below code and you will get the idea of what I am trying to say.

unionList=list(enumerate(sorted(aCounter.items()|bCounter.items())))
print(unionList)
print(idDict)

If you want you may correct the above solution of yours.

Thanks a lot.
@Mehrdad Dowlatabadi

Comment: In my question above I have mentioned that I want to 'store them in file and retrive them for use'. Is it possible for you to complete this solution of yours?
@Mehrdad Dowlatabadi

Comment: I am not asking about writing a file.
I want to know that how would you write this output 

[(0, 'a', 5), (1, 'b', 4), (3, 'd', 1), (4, 'e', 1)]
[(0, 'a', 10), (1, 'b', 7), (2, 'c', 8), (3, 'd', 2), (4, 'e', 1)]

and retrive it and would use the information around some ID and element.

Comment: Okay Brother if you liked this question then kindly up mark this question, I am under New user restriction.

Comment: Sorry brother, the above answer is not correct as earlier you were taking items like this sorted(aCounter.tems()|bCounter.tems()) so idDict={item[0]:i for i,item in enumerate(v) } was correct as item was having two value, but now as you are taking keys like v=sorted(aCounter.keys()|bCounter.keys()) now item is returning only one element and now if you write item[0] then it will take first charecter of the item consedering item as an array of charecters. Now the correct one is idDict={item:i for i,item in enumerate(v) }.
Please Correct, @Mehrdad Dowlatabadi